# Detectar el idioma del navegador con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código para detectar el idioma del navegador:

```
<?php 
  //Creamos una función que detecte el idioma del navegador del cliente.
  function getUserLanguage() { 
       $idioma =substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2);
       return $idioma; 
  }

  //Almacenamos dicho idioma en una variable
  $user_language=getUserLanguage();

  //De acuerdo al idioma hacemos una o varias redirecciones.
  if($user_language=='en'){
       header( 'Location: http://www.ejemplo.travel/en' );
  }
  elseif($user_language=='de'){
       header( 'Location: http://www.ejemplo.com/de' );
  }
?>
```

Pero tengo mi web traducida a español,inglés, francés, alemán, e italiano. Me gustaria saber que opciones devuelve a parte de las del ejemplo "en","de" dependiendo de los idiomas que yo tengo traudcidos.. Por ejemplo.. francés es "fr", italiano es "it" ?? y alemán ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al ejecutar la funcion **getUserLanguage()** podria devolver cualquiera de todos estos, ya te tocaria elegir cuales quieres darles soporte y cuales no, ya que si son bastantes

```
$langs = array(
'af', // afrikaans.
'ar', // arabic.
'bg', // bulgarian.
'ca', // catalan.
'cs', // czech.
'da', // danish.
'de', // german.
'el', // greek.
'en', // english.
'es', // spanish.
'et', // estonian.
'fi', // finnish.
'fr', // french.
'gl', // galician.
'he', // hebrew.
'hi', // hindi.
'hr', // croatian.
'hu', // hungarian.
'id', // indonesian.
'it', // italian.
'ja', // japanese.
'ko', // korean.
'ka', // georgian.
'lt', // lithuanian.
'lv', // latvian.
'ms', // malay.
'nl', // dutch.
'no', // norwegian.
'pl', // polish.
'pt', // portuguese.
'ro', // romanian.
'ru', // russian.
'sk', // slovak.
'sl', // slovenian.
'sq', // albanian.
'sr', // serbian.
'sv', // swedish.
'th', // thai.
'tr', // turkish.
'uk', // ukrainian.
'zh' // chinese.
);
```

Answer (score 1):

si solo quieres que tradusca a los idiomas que tienes definidos puedes hacer un:

```
<?php
  // alamacenara todos nuestro idiomas
  $idiomas = array("EN", "IT", "ES", "DE");

  //Creamos una función que detecte el idioma del navegador del cliente.
  function getUserLanguage() { 
       $idioma =substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2);
       return $idioma; 
  }

  //Almacenamos dicho idioma en una variable.
  $user_language=getUserLanguage();

  // pasamos el language a mayuscula para no tener errores.
  //verificamos que tengamos dicho idioma en nuestro arreglo con in_array.
  if (in_array(strtoupper($user_language), $idiomas)) {
       // ahora redirigimos al idioma correcto
       header( 'Location: http://www.ejemplo.travel/'.$user_language);
  }

  else{ // en caso contrario mandamos un idioma por defecto 

       header( 'Location: http://www.ejemplo.com/en' );
  }
?>
```